# Add item to a list in realtime in a wordpress template

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, templates

I'm working on a wordpress template and there is one textbox and a button. 
I would need to archieve that when i type something in the box and press the button, the page writes this value in the database and then adds a new row to a table on this very same page containing the newely added item. All this without the page beeing reloaded.

As far as I know i need to use jquery to do this, but how is this PROPERLY done inside a wordpress template by using the tools wordpress provides me with?

Comment: I haven't used Wordpress in a very long time, but I doubt it has the tools you'd need built-in. I would suggest posting the code for your template and the database structure you'll be using.

Answer (score 0):

Even without knowing how wordpress handles custom javascript code, I assume that you can import a custom JS script in the document. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript).

What you need to do is to bind the click event of the button (`.click()` or with the `on()` function), and in the callback you can retrieve the value of the text box (`$("textbox_selector").val()`).

After that you can use the [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (or the [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) / [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post) shorthands depending on which kind of request you need).
To add a new row to the table you can create a new tr element with `$("<tr>")`, adding the various `<td>` in the same way or using the `html()` function to directly set the html inside.
Then you can use the `append()` function on the table selector.

P.S.: you say that "As far as I know i need to use jquery to do this" so I assume it's only about the client side. Do you need even the server side? If the answer is yes, we need at least the DB structure and other server-side info, and then I can integrate the answer.
Anyway the PHP script will be part of your template and it will be responsible to add the entry in the DB and returning some useful message that will be available in the `$.ajax()` callback function.